# build rqt from source?

Tags: ubuntu, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I build rqt from source on ubuntu/indigo?  Instructions on using a catkin workspace on the ros wiki page are incomplete.  I'm looking for just a few instructions like mkdir build/cd build/cmake ../make etc (those that exact sequence doesn't work here).

Thanks!

Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195121/build-rqt-from-source?/) by [steve](https://answers.ros.org/users/20486/steve/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Building `rqt` or `rqt_common_plugins` from source should not be any different from any other ROS package.  The general idea would be to obtain copies of the package source code, put them in a workspace, install any system dependencies, and then run `catkin_make`. Here is a set of commands that I believe would do what you want

```
1 $  cd 
2 $  mkdir -p ~/rqt_ws/src
3 $  cd rqt_ws/src
4 $  source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
5 $  catkin_init_workspace
6 $  cd ..
7 $  catkin_make
8 $  source devel/setup.bash
9 $  cd src/
10 $  git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt
11 $  git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins
12 $  rosdep update
13 $  rosdep install --from-paths ./ --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y --simulate
14 $  rosdep install --from-paths ./ --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
15 $  cd ..
16 $  catkin_make
```

In the above, the first  8 lines are just [creating a new workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). Lines 9-11 are getting copies of the two packages. Lines 12-14 are installing any missing dependencies, and lines 15-16 are building the new workspace.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow the [Beginner Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and all your questions will be answered.

BTW: Please delete your duplicate question.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1